# Not understanding how the bitwise unary inversion ' ~ ' operator works

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

```
int x=10;
cout<<~x;
```

this code prints -11. if it was simple inversion then for 00001010 the bits should be 11110101, which on conversion to decimal is -117. I have tried searching but no luck pls tell what is happening here?
I am using mingw compiler, if its of any help.

Comment: 0b11110101 is not -117 when interpreted as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Incidentally, `int` is at the very least 16 bit wide (and typically 32 bit wide).

Comment: It rarely makes sense to apply `~` to signed integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is working as expected.  "11110101" is -11 in two's complement.

As a side note, "int" is either 16 or 32 bits, so you're actually talking about
"00000000 00001010" or "00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010" respectively.

Comment: `int` is *at least* 16 bits, but it doesn't have to be either 16 or 32. (I've used systems where `int` is 64 bits.)

Answer (score 2):

`~x` is equal to `−x − 1`. Therefore, `~10 = -10 - 1` = `-11`.

Using 1-byte , `10` is represented as `0000 1010`. Its bit-wise NOT is `1111 0101`. Generally computer represents signed integers in 2's complement format. So, decimal equivalent of `1111 0101` is `-11`, How?

An N-bit number *w* represented in 2's complement as *a<sub>N-1</sub>a<sub>N-2</sub>....a<sub>0</sub>* can be converted to decimal as

[image]

Therefore,

1111 0101<sub>2</sub> = -1*2<sup>7</sup>  1*2<sup>6</sup> + 1*2<sup>5</sup> + 1*2<sup>4</sup> + 0*2<sup>3</sup> + 1*2<sup>2</sup> + 0*2<sup>1</sup> + 1*2<sup>0</sup>  = -128 + 117 = -11

Comment: 2's complement is not the only method for representing signed integers, though it's by far the most common. The C standard explicitly permits either 2's-complement, 1's-complement, or sign-and-magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ operator works as you think it does. It's just negative numbers don't work how you think they do. Negative numbers are encoded as a two's complement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Basically, the value of the highest bit is subtracted from the value of the lower bits.

Comment: Bear in mind C says nothing about how negative numbers are encoded - any system could in theory be used.

Comment: @teppic :That's not quite true. Starting with the C99 standard, it only permits 2's-complement, 1's-complement, and sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, I didn't know C99 had limited the possibilities. Still, taking it for granted that 2's complement is always used is a very common thing.

Comment: The best idea might be not to rely on the behavior. Using bitwise operations only on unsigned types of a known size would solve the problem.